# Why is the cookie not being sent with Axios requests despite being set in the server response and CORS configuration?

Tags: java, spring, cookies, axios, samesite

I'm working on a web application that uses Java Spring on the server side and React on the client side. The server sends a cookie in the response when the user logs in, and subsequent requests from the client are expected to include this cookie for authentication. However, the cookie doesn't seem to be sent with the request, and I'm not sure why.

Here's the server-side code that sets the set-cookie header:

```
ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("my_cookie", "my_value")
  .httpOnly(true)
  .secure(false)
  .sameSite("lax")
  .build();
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());
```

And here's the client-side code that makes the request to refresh the access token:

```
axios.get('/api/v1/auth/refresh_token', { withCredentials: true })
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

And here's the server-side code that sets the CORS configuration:

```
public class CorsConfiguration {
    @Value("${navaship.webapp.url}")
    private String webAppUrl;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                // Add the CORS configuration for the /api/v1/auth/refresh-token endpoint
                registry.addMapping("/api/v*/auth/refresh-token")
                        .allowedOrigins(webAppUrl)
                        .allowedMethods("GET")
                        .allowCredentials(true);

                registry.addMapping("/api/v*/**")
                        .allowedOrigins(webAppUrl)
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I've verified that the cookie is being set properly in the server response, and that the allowCredentials option is set to true in the CORS configuration for the /api/v1/auth/refresh-token endpoint. However, when I inspect the network requests in the browser console, I don't see the cookie being sent in the request headers.

What could be causing the cookie to not be sent with the request? Is there anything I'm missing in my code or configuration? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `.secure(true)`

Reason is that `.secure` only allows cookies to be transmitted via secure channels which is HTTPS. If you are developing locally, chances are you are using http so no cookie.

Also keep in mind that `.httpOnly(true)` will prevent your js code (so your react app) from accessing cookie. So in case your js code needs to read the cookie value you will need to disable it.

Comment: oh sorry it should be false there, I updated my question

Comment: then try removing `.sameSite` setting because that could be an issue if the domains are not the same

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: unfortunately I cant help you with the information given. You need to urself analyze where exactly the problem first occurs. In the question you are asking about the refresh_token request but is the cookie ever set in the very first authorization request?. Use developer tools to check Application -> Cookies and keep going through the steps till u know where it first goes missing